# if $u$ is a harmonic function, then $u$ has a harmonic conjugate.

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, cauchy-riemann-equations

I have a question about a theorem and its proof from the book, Functions of one complex variable(John B. Conway) 3.2 section.

**Theorem:**

Let $\pmb{G}$ be either the whole plane $\mathbb{C}$ or some open disk. if $ u: \pmb{G} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a harmonic function then $u$ has a harmonic conjugate.

**Proof:**

Let $\pmb{G} = \pmb{B}(0; R)$, $0\lt R \leq \infty$ and let $ u: \pmb{G} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a harmonic function. The proof will be accomplished by finding a harmonic function $v$ such that $u$ and $v$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equation. so define

$\mathit{v}(x,y) = \int^y_0u_x(x,t)dt+\phi(x)$

and determine $\phi$ so that $v_x=-u_x$. differentiating both sides of this equation with respect to $x$ gives

$v_x(x,y)= \int^y_0u_{xx}(x,t)dt+ \phi'(x)$

$=-\int_0^yu_{yy}(x,t)dt+\phi'$

$=-u_y(x,y)+u_y(x,0)+\phi'(x)$

so it must be that $\phi'(x)=-u_y(x,0)$. It is easily checked that $u$ and

$v(x,y)=\int_0^yu_x(x,t)dt - \int_0^xu_y(s,0)ds$

do satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

---

So, my question is that where we used an open disk or whole $\mathbb{C}$ to prove this theorem? (according to the statement)

Could someone explain where it went wrong if the region is not simply connected?

Comment: simply connectedness of domain is necessary for the well-definedness of the $v$ constructed.

Comment: So why an open ball and why not close?

Comment: @Paul derivatives play nice on open sets since we can approach from all directions and thus use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: @r9m could you explain your comment

Comment: Lot of people has same questions, it could be helpful if someone add answer to this

Comment: @CloudJR The way I understand harmonic conjugate is that to get a holomorphic function $f$ such that $u,v$ are the real and imaginary parts of $f$. Now, $\Delta u = 4\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} u = 0$ therefore, $g := \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ is a holomorphic function and a suitable 'primitive' of $g$ should serve as the function $f$. So we define $\displaystyle f(z) := \int_{[0,z]} g(\zeta)\,d\zeta$ where, $[0,z]$ is a countour joining $0$ and $z$ in the domain. The welldefinedness of the integral requires simply connected domains.

Comment: Why well definedness require simply connected region?

Comment: Consider the usual $g(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, then $\displaystyle \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{\,dz}{z} - \int_{\gamma_2} \frac{\,dz}{z} = 2\pi i \neq 0$, where, $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are two contours joining $-1$ and $1$ (say) along the upper and lower arcs of the unit circle. Thus $\frac{1}{z}$ doesn't have a well defined 'primitive' in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. This is precisely what creates [branches of holomorphic functions](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Branch_of_an_analytic_function).